# How to get username with user id in this query? (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

I have figured out most of my SQL query, but I seem to need a little help.

I can't seem to figure out how to select `username` from `user` by using `social_posts.user_id`.

Here's my query (that works):

```
SELECT social_posts.user_id, social_posts.post_stamp, social_posts.message
FROM social_posts
WHERE id IN (
SELECT social_threads.id 
FROM social_threads, friends 
WHERE (((friends.user_a = ?) || (friends.user_b = ?)) && (friends.request = 1)) || (social_threads.user_id = ?)
ORDER BY social_threads.id DESC)
LIMIT 15
```

I would like the query to return `user.username`. In the `user` table, the user id is called `id`.

When I try the following I get an error:

```
SELECT social_posts.user_id, social_posts.post_stamp, social_posts.message, user.username
FROM social_posts
INNER JOIN user ON social_posts.user_id = user.id

WHERE id IN (
SELECT social_threads.id 
FROM social_threads, friends 
WHERE (((friends.user_a = ?) || (friends.user_b = ?)) && (friends.request = 1)) || (social_threads.user_id = ?)
ORDER BY social_threads.id DESC)

LIMIT 15
```

That query returns the following error:
`Column 'id' in IN/ALL/ANY subquery is ambiguous`

Although this works:

```
SELECT social_posts.user_id, social_posts.post_stamp, social_posts.message, user.username
FROM social_posts
INNER JOIN user ON social_posts.user_id = user.id
LIMIT 15
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What error do you get? (we are not psychic)

Comment: @Bohemian Sorry about that, the error that I'm getting is `Column 'id' in IN/ALL/ANY subquery is ambiguous`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT social_posts.user_id, social_posts.post_stamp, social_posts.message, user.username
FROM social_posts , user
WHERE social_posts.id IN (
SELECT social_threads.id 
FROM social_threads, friends 
WHERE (((friends.user_a = ?) || (friends.user_b = ?)) && (friends.request = 1)) || (social_threads.user_id = ?)
ORDER BY social_threads.id DESC)
AND social_posts.user_id = user.id
LIMIT 15
```

I assume that `Order By` clause is with inner query,

Comment: It seems to be returning `Unknown column 'social_posts.user_id' in 'field list'`.

Comment: @JoshFoskett that was the issue with table alias, have edited the query. Removed the table aliases from the "from" clause. Please try now